# Is there a way to stop Mail from downloading e-mail when using IMAP?

Tags: mail.app, macos

In Sierra, and it looks like this started with Mavericks, Mail downloads to a local disk entire e-mail messages when using IMAP.

It used not to do this in Mountain Lion (10.8).

Is there a way to configure Mail in Sierra to download just e-mail headers when using IMAP?